# Show content from different parts or fields in Orchard template

Tags: orchardcms

I have a content type with a title part, a body part and a content picker field.

The overall template for the type *content.cshtml* controls where the meta, content and footer info is shown. The placement file controls whether a part is in the meta, content or footer.

Each part has it's own template, but I want to make the title link to the content picker's content item, so I need to show information from a part and a field.

Should I (and can I):

1. Create an alternative of content.cshtml and directly display the content of the parts and fields directly.
2. Create an alternative of Parts.Title.cshtml and reference the content picker field somehow.

Which solution is best and what would that template look like? Or, is there a better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd opt for the second solution and create either an alternate for your title part or for the field and leave content as it is.

So if your content was called TestContent, you could create an alternate called

```
Parts.Title-TestContent.cshtml
```

And if your content picker field was called MyContentPicker you could access it from your new alternate like so

```
var url = Url.ItemDisplayUrl((Orchard.ContentManagement.IContent) Model.ContentItem.TestContent.MyContentPicker.ContentItems[0]);
```

Then slip that into a href and you are good to go. I'm not sure if this is the correct way to do things, but it should work. Maybe someone else has a better way they might share :)

Comment: 2 was my preferred option, and your code works when TestContent = name of content type and MyContentPicker = name of my content picker field. Still interested to see if there is a 3rd better way. If not, will mark this as answer.

Comment: Yeah, when using Orchard I get into this frame of mind where everything must be separated and not know about anything else...ever! But often you want fields and parts to interact ^_^